# Android - Google Maps - Show region by zipcode or pincode

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

When I search a valid pincode or zipcode in google maps web version, it highlights the entire region which belongs to that pincode. See below screenshot.

How to similate the same thing in my Android app which has the google map integration?

[image]

Comment: Well, I think it is not yet available in the [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start). I found this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4008) related to your issue.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the information.